# Is it reliable/safe using imageload/store on an image2D, but also read from it using texture(), as sampler2D?

Tags: image, opengl, textures

Initially I wanted to render an image2D to a texture, so I can stretch it and use filtering. Then I've ended up with the below, stumbling upon this capability, and I'm not sure if this is safe to use.

```
glGenTextures(1, @RenderTarget);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, RenderTarget);

// numerous glTexParameterf

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, // ... etc

glBindImageTexture(0, RenderTarget, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);

glUniform1i(Uniform('Image'), 0);
glUniform1i(Uniform('RenderTarget'), 0);

glUniform1i(Uniform('MaxScreenX'),MaxScreenX);
glUniform1i(Uniform('MaxScreenY'),MaxScreenY);


// ------------------------------------------------------------- Fills the Image
glUniform1i(Uniform('Procedure'), 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glFinish;

// ------------------------------------------------------------- Displays the Texture
glUniform1i(Uniform('Procedure'), 2);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
SwapBuffers(DeviceContext);
glFinish;
```

VertexShader:

```
#version 450 core

void main()
{
    float x = -1.0 + float((gl_VertexID & 1) << 2);
    float y = -1.0 + float((gl_VertexID & 2) << 1);

    gl_Position = vec4(x, y, 0, 1);
}
```

FragmentShader:

```
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0, RGBA8) uniform image2D Image;
layout(location = 1, RGBA8) uniform sampler2D RenderTarget;

uniform int Procedure;
uniform int MaxScreenX;
uniform int MaxScreenY;

vec2 MaxScreen = vec2(MaxScreenX,MaxScreenY);

out vec4 Pixel;
void main()
{
    Pixel = vec4(1.0);

    if (Procedure == 0)
    {
        imageStore(Image,ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy),vec4(int(int(gl_FragCoord.x*gl_FragCoord.y) % 8 == 0) * (gl_FragCoord.xy / MaxScreen)*4,0.0,0.0));
        return;
    }
    
    if (Procedure == 2)
    {
        vec4 TextureData = texture(RenderTarget,(gl_FragCoord.xy / MaxScreen));

        Pixel = vec4(TextureData.xyz,1.0);
        return;
    }

    return;
}
```

With a 1024x1024 RenderTarget, stretched to full screen:

[image]

With a full screen RenderTarget:
[image]

It works fine, but is it reliable?

Comment: Update! I've switched from the AMD APU to the dedicated 3060 and now get the message: "0(3) : error C1315: can't apply layout(rgba8) to non-image". I've fixed that and now it works as expected even on the 3060.

Comment: Your program only does one at a time, so I don't see why it would be a problem

Comment: @user253751 It's not memory access that bothers me. My worry is that being able to have the same data bound as both image and texture might be unreliable. The little information I find isn't conclusive. Some people even say it's not possible at all, yet it clearly is.